# Kafka Streams | How to add the "to" topic dynamically on the basis of content received over stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My question is simple, yet I am unable to figure out how to achieve below using Kafka streams in Java?

1. I've a created a Kafka stream which is connected to a topic.
2. On that topic, I receive a json which contains data and the name of another topic.

I want to forward the received json content to that another topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Kafka 1.1 or older, you would need to use `KStream#branch()` to split the stream into sub-stream (one per output topic) and then add a sink (ie, `KStream#to()` for each output topic.

In upcoming 2.0 release, a dynamic routing feature is added, that allows you to extract a sink-topic name dynamically base on the message content. Cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-303%3A+Add+Dynamic+Routing+in+Streams+Sink for details.

Comment: If I use branch(), then there also I can't add sink dynamically. Matt, do you mean till 2.0 release, I can't implement this using Streams?

Comment: Correct, branch() is more static than dynamic routing. AK 2.0 is planned to be release end of June: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=80448820

Comment: To "play" you can also build Kafka from the source yourself until it's officially release. Not too hard to do.